# Market update deletes the stored data

Tags: android, cordova, web-sql

I made an phonegap app, which is using websql for storing data. Everything works fine, it is on Google Play. The problem is when I update it (from the market) it erases all of the data which is stored in the websql. My question is, how can I solve this problem? How can I solve it, not to erase all of the data, when I update is?